# How can I click on numeric buttons (onclick Event) using selenum in python?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, click, buttonclick

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<ul aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="resultsPerPage-button" id="resultsPerPage-menu" role="listbox" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-corner-bottom ui-widget ui-widget-content" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-2" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 71px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">20</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active">50</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">100</div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">200</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to click on "200". Can u help me? I used selenium in python 2.7

I tried doing this:

```
import time 

time.sleep(10) 
x=driver.find_element_by_link_text("200").click() 
x.click() 
time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: can you share what've you done so far?

Comment: Try using something like this: `driver.find_element_by_link_text("200").click()`

Comment: This error will be shown by your suggestion:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: 200

Comment: Can you please share the GUI of given html code

Comment: Try using some delay before that line. Btw, where is your code? You should paste here your code to get a more specific answer.

Comment: try this xpath: `//div[text()='200']`

Comment: import time

time.sleep(10)
x=driver.find_element_by_link_text("200").click()
x.click()
time.sleep(8)

Comment: @hamedbaziyad please edit and update your question, your comment is unreadable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the element that contains the text `200` is not a "Link", but only a `li` tag which could work as a clickable element was defined on that site.

The [documentation](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/selenium-python-2.45.0/#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text) doesn't specify it directly, but **"Link" means only `a` tags**.

The idea is the same, but you'll have to find that element on a different way than thinking about as a Link. Using xpath would be I think the best way for this approach:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[./text()='200']")
x.click()
```

Now of course that would work for finding an element depending on the `text` it contains, but for finding the specific node you want would be even easier and better to use the `id`, as it should always be unique:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-4')
```

Comment: It is not wrong. But, without the use of send_key, it doesn't work. My HTML code shows that the button is a drop-down button which needs a combination of methods for click process. So, use of send_key() seems essential before your suggestion ( x = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-4')).

Answer (score 1):

I can run it by use of "send_keys":

```
import time
number.click()
number.send_keys("200")
var200=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ui-id-4"]""")
var200.click()
```